# WinRt page navigation

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

How do you navigate to a page from code that is inside of a custom class.  For example, lets say I have this code in my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var work = new Work();
   work.doMore();
}
```

and in this class here is where I would like the navigation to actually take place:

```
public class Work
{
   public void DoMore()
   {
      // this is what I've tried, but doesn't work
      var myFrame = new Frame();
      myFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you tried doesn't work because is not the main frame, you should publish the MainFrame reference to the rest of your code so that you can navigate outside views code behind. 
If you are making something simple I recommend putting a static property on the App class publishing the main frame instance.

EDIT: Some code

```
On App.xaml.cs
      public static Frame MainFrame{get;private set;}

      protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
            {
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                MainFrame = rootFrame;
(....)
            }
Usage:
       App.MainFrame.Navigate(...);
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am very new at this.

Comment: check the edit I just made. As I said there is fancy ways to do this, but for know this should be enough to get you going

Comment: Excellent! I got it now. Thank you for your explanation and time.